# Customizing/Overriding CSS using Tailwind (in this case React-Image-Gallery)

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, image-gallery

What is best practice when you want to override/customize styling, if you are using Tailwind?

In this specific case, I want to change the height and color of the "navigation arrow" of the package React-Image-Gallery, but I've had the same challenge before with other packages.

I love using tailwind, but I miss being able to create a separate CSS file, find the CSS className and modify it in a CSS file (sometimes the dirty way with !important to force it..).

Any best practice for doing this?

Best regards,
Oscar

Comment: try this: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens

Comment: This does not seem to work :-(